# can't merge master branch to gh-pages

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I have checked out gh-pages branch. I try `git merge master` and I receive the following "error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge: ... Please move or remove them before you can merge."  That's exactly what I want to do.  I want the files on the master branch to override the versions of those same files on the gh-pages branch.  I have read up a little on versions of the `git rm...` command and also tried `git stash` and `git reset head`.  I still get the same error.

In short, how do I ignore the current status of gh-pages and overwrite them with master branch?

Comment: Can you provide the entire output after `git merge master`?

Comment: If you want to override entirely, perhaps you could just delete the files that git warns about from the gh-pages folder entirely?

Comment: @mms27 the quote above, starting with "error:..." is the entire output except for the list of files that were causing the error/conflict.

Comment: @Ber That's basically what I did although I took the more severe approach of deleting the entire branch.  Seemed like there must have been a better way though..

Answer (score 1):

You have some untracked files on your current branch that are versioned on master branch. Merging master (or checking out master) would overwrite them without the possibility to reverse that. Git always tries to prevent you from loosing data that cannot be restored until you explicitly told it to do so. Here are the things you can do:

1. git clean -f (but first run --dry-run to see if you don't delete something you actually don't want to remove)
2. Delete listed files using rm (not git rm)
3. git stash -u
4. add untracked files, commit them and then merge.

and probably many other things to get rid of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to keep the current untracked files in your working tree for `gh-pages` then you could blast them away and perform the merge:

```
git reset --hard
git merge master
```

If you do want to keep those files you can `add` then `commit` them, and then do the `git merge master`

Comment: it won't solve his problem since git reset (even with --hard mode) leaves all untracked files

Comment: Correct.  None of these things worked.  I ended up deleting the entire branch, since its only purpose is to make the content viewable through free github hosting and the content was already backed up on the master branch and all of the changes were tracked in the development branch.  There must be a clean way to do this though.  I would still like to know how to do this though... and how I got in the place where I got the merge conflict in the first place.