# Attempted git merge aborts without any error

Tags: git, git-merge

```
C:\Users\danie01\fox (fox-45481 -> origin)
λ git merge feature/master-stg
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        blah/blah/blahblah.cpp
        ... (many files)
        common/wizard/wizpa
Aborting

C:\Users\danie01\fox (fox-45481 -> origin)
λ
```

It's been a very long time since I previously merged. Further, the last commit in this branch was a merge.

Interestingly, the final file in this list is cut off (it doesn't have the file extension or complete the file name even) - could this be an issue with my buffer?

I have just recently checked this out from a remote branch; I do not have permissions to merge into a remote branch and need to create a merge request. Could it be the case that git is trying to merge directly into the remote branch?

What can be done here? I am at a loss.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't merge master branch to gh-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23572280/cant-merge-master-branch-to-gh-pages)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-merge%5D+error%3A+The+following+untracked+working+tree+files+would+be+overwritten+by+merge

Answer (score 2):

> Could it be the case that git is trying to merge directly into the remote branch?

No.  That's not how Git performs merges.

(Incidentally, your subject line is wrong, as the merge aborts *with* an error, telling you that certain untracked files would be overwritten.)

> Interestingly, the final file in this list is cut off (it doesn't have the file extension or complete the file name even) - could this be an issue with my buffer?

I'm not sure what you mean by that, but certainly the file names in the output should not be truncated.

Note that when you ask Git to do a merge, it must juggle several different items.  All *commits* are frozen (read-only) and essentially permanent,<sup>1</sup> so they are not a problem.  But there are two things that are *not* frozen and therefore may be overwritten:

- Your current index content.  Your index holds one—or sometimes (during an incomplete merge) more than one—entry for each *tracked file* in the work-tree.  In fact, that's what a tracked file is: it's a file that is in the work-tree right now that is also in the index right now.<sup>2</sup>
- Your current work-tree content.  Git doesn't use this directly—it's there for *you* to use—but various operations will, of course, *overwrite* files in the work-tree.  For instance, `git checkout` of some other branch is obviously going to have to overwrite at least a few files, if the other branch has different file contents.

Between these two things, it's easy for you to create *untracked files*.  An untracked file is simply a file that exists in your work-tree right now, but that is not in your index right now.  Each such file can be either ignored or not ignored, but either way, it's untracked.  If it's *not* ignored, `git status` will complain about it.

Before you start a merge, it's a good idea to make sure of two things: first, that you're not already in the middle of some other operation, and second, that your `HEAD` commit, index, and work-tree all match in terms of all your tracked files.  The `git merge` command does most of this automatically but it's never a bad idea to run `git status` first and make sure that it says `nothing to commit, working tree clean`.

It's OK if this also complains about various untracked files, as we get a chance to deal with them in a moment.  Now that you are sure that there is no in-progress work that might be lost, you issue your merge command:

```
λ git merge feature/master-stg
```

What Git does now is:

- Look up the hash ID of the current commit (`git rev-parse HEAD`).
- Look up the hash ID of the specified commit (`git rev-parse feature/master-stg`).
- Use `git merge-base --all` to find the merge base(s) of these two commits.  The merge base is a commit, or sometimes more than one commit, that is on *both* branches, and is the *best* such commit.

Ideally, there's only one merge base commit.  You can verify whether this is the case by running:

```
git merge-base --all HEAD feature/master-stg
```

If it prints out just one hash ID, that's the (single) merge base commit.  Getting multiple merge bases here is rare, and if it happens, this requires more discussion, but since it *is* rare (and probably not happening here) we can just assume there's only the one merge base.

In some cases, there's just the one merge base *and* it's the *same* hash ID as the current (`HEAD`) commit.  These cases are generally very easy to handle and Git defaults to doing a *fast-forward* operation instead of a merge.  Probably yours is not such a case (but it could be—there's no evidence here one way or the other).  I'll assume that Git is doing a real merge, since the problem is going to be the same either way, and the solution is going to be the same.

---

<sup>1</sup>Files inside a commit are definitely frozen, but they exist in that form *because* the commit exists.  If you manage to get Git to forget about that commit, the commit itself will eventually vanish.  It's very hard to do this, so commits are *mostly* permanent.  They are *completely* read-only, though: nothing in any commit, as identified by its hash ID, can ever change.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, you can remove the work-tree copy while leaving the index copy in place.  That would still be a "tracked file", I think, although the nomenclature gets a little shaky.  (How can a file be tracked if that file doesn't exist?)

---

#### How Git performs a real merge

Now that Git knows the three *inputs* to the merge—the base commit, the `--ours` or `HEAD` commit, and the other or `--theirs` commit, from `feature/master-stg`, Git will, in effect, run *two* `git diff` commands:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-base> HEAD                # what we changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-base> feature/master-stg  # what they changed
```

The *job* of the merge is now pretty simple and pretty obvious.  This is what it will have to do:

- Start with all the files that were in the merge base commit.
- Then, if *we* changed or created or removed (and/or renamed) a file, and *they* didn't touch the file, use *our* change.
- If *they* changed or created or removed (and/or renamed) a file, and *we* didn't touch the file, use *their* change.
- If we and they both changed or created or removed (and/or renamed) *the same* file, *combine* these two separate sets of changes.

In simple cases, doing all of this is pretty simple.  For instance, perhaps we both touched `README.md`, but on different lines; we changed `a/main.py` and they didn't; and they changed `b/prog.cc` and we didn't.  The result of the merge, then, will be all the base files, except for `README.md`, which has the combined changes, our `a/main.py`, and their `b/prog.cc`.

If all goes well, Git commits the resulting files, putting them into your index and work-tree along the way.  The new commit updates the current branch, so that whatever branch `HEAD` names, now names the new commit.  The new commit's first parent is the previous tip of the current branch, and the new commit's second parent is the other commit (the one still identified by `feature/master-stg`, in this case).  Since the new commit has two parents, it is a *merge commit*.

In complicated cases, something goes wrong, and the merge either stops in the middle—which is the messiest case—or never starts.  You have the latter case: the merge never starts.

#### You have untracked files that they have in their commit

What's going wrong here is that in *their* commit—the one named by `feature/master-stg`—*they* have some files committed, that:

- are not in the merge base commit, and
- are not in your HEAD commit either.

Git has printed out the complete list of these files:

> ```
> blah/blah/blahblah.cpp
> ... (many files)
> common/wizard/wizpa
> ```

In the `git diff --find-renames <hash of merge base> feature/master-sta` output, *they* have *added these files*.  You can confirm this by running that same `git diff` yourself, perhaps with `--name-status` so that it's shorter and more readable.

You don't have those files in your `HEAD` commit, but you *do* have these very same files in your *work-tree* right now.

For Git to do the merge and get the final result in place, Git will have to *overwrite* your work-tree files.  Since they're not in your index and not in your commit, Git cannot be sure that it's OK to destroy the only copy of them, sitting in the work-tree.  Git therefore aborts the merge, never starting it at all.

The solution is to do just what Git said, or should have said (maybe it's lost in the "blahblahblah" part):

> Please move or remove them before you merge.

Essentially, Git feels the need to overwrite these files.  If it does so, *whatever contents you have in them* will be irretrievable—or at least, *Git* won't be able to get it back.  So you must save the contents elsewhere, if they are valuable.

Answer (score 1):

I think that git is trying to tell you that by running the merge, some files that, on your current working tree are, they not being tracked, on the other branch they are tracked and so they would be overwritten if you merge. I guess you could just delete them from your working tree so that the merge goes through.